# How can one define an external "builder tool" for Dart using sbt/play 2.0?

Tags: playframework, sbt, dart

Currently Play2.0 supports coffee script to javascript and less to css "out of the box" in the /app/assets directory.

Is there a way to get similar functionality (presumably via configuring the sbt inside play 2.0) for dart?  If done right, it would result in frogc's (or dart2js') js output being made available programmatically in assets, but of course really being in resources_managed.

Answer (score 4):

I remembered that this was raised in the Play Google Group a while back, so did a quick search. It appears someone has got this working

https://github.com/nelsonsilva/Play20/commit/b365ca56aa285355752d39487fc38a40ad88be5e

based on [this converstaion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/4xc_gTtOBl0).

There does not appear to be an actual module for this yet though (as of 22/5/2012).

Comment: This seems to be making direct calls to the old dartc code since it was written in Java. This would now need call dart2js.